# error in DialogFragment show() method

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I am getting  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed.** when i try to show a dialogfragment from an activity.

I have seen many solutions in stackoverflow but those didnt solve my problem
Error occurs in the following line

> dialogfragment.show(ft, "dialog");

Code is given below.

```
class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

int mNum = 0;
static MyDialog newInstance(){
    return new MyDialog();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //dialog view
    Log.i("MyDialog", "onCreateview");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
    TextView v1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    v1.setText("dialog shown");
    return v;
}

}


public class DialogActivity extends FragmentActivity{

DialogFragment dialogfragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
void show(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");

    if(f != null){
        ft.remove(f);
    }

    dialogfragment = MyDialog.newInstance();

    dialogfragment.setCancelable(false);
    dialogfragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    dialogfragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);

}
}
```

I am calling this method from an Activity class as

```
DialogActivity dl = new DialogActivity();
    dl.show();
```

Error log

> 07-08 14:54:09.565: W/System.err(10390): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
>   07-08 14:54:09.565: W/System.err(10390):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1314)
>   07-08 14:54:09.565: W/System.err(10390):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
>   07-08 14:54:09.565: W/System.err(10390):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
>   07-08 14:54:09.565: W/System.err(10390):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:138)

I missed some part of code.now added it

EDIT :

> Is there anyother way to call the show() method in DialogActivity from
>   another Activity class??

Comment: you can check this if it helps http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. as blackbelt suggested you need to start an activity. activity has a lifecycle. `DialogActivity dl = new DialogActivity()` this won't start an activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
DialogActivity dl = new DialogActivity();
dl.show();
```

you can not instatiate an `Activity` with the new operator. The `Activity` has its own lifecycle, and you should use `Intent`s with `startActivity` to start an `Activity` . Probably you should extends `DialogFragment` instead of `FragmentActivity`

Comment: thnks i changed that.but dialog is showing as if new activity is loaded.not only small dialog but some entire new screen is coming

Comment: probably it is an issue related to the custom layout

Comment: I am starting this from an  Activity class like thisway. startActivity(new Intent(this,DialogActivity.class));